# Enable automatic minor core updates when root of site is a git repository

Tags: automatic-updates, git

I have a client site that's under version control using Git. The single repository is at the Wordpress root level, but it is set to ignore everything except for theme and plugin files. I did some research into best practices and found some content on submodules, which I might try next time, but at the moment, I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve both of the following:

1. Keep the Git repository structured as is at the WordPress root but effectively only use it to version control theme and plugins in a single repository.
2. Enable automatic WordPress core updates and get around this error: `This site appears to be under version control. Automatic updates are disabled.`

[image: This site appears to be under version control. Automatic updates are disabled.]

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/52279

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding this filter in a [must-use plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/) or [functions.php](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/#what-is-functions-php) will allow [automatic updates](https://wordpress.org/support/article/configuring-automatic-background-updates/) even if the site is under version control:

```
add_filter( 'automatic_updates_is_vcs_checkout', '__return_false', 1 );
```

From https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/automatic_updates_is_vcs_checkout/